# Apache Spark: get the executor ID in the map reduce pipeline

Tags: java, apache-spark

Small question regarding how to get the Spark executor ID in a Apache Spark job please.

I have a very straightforward piece of code:

```java
final Dataset<Row> rowDataSet = sparkSession.read()[...].load();
final Dataset<String> stringDataSet = rowDataSet
        .map(
                (MapFunction<Row, String>) row -> 
                        doSomeTransformationFromRowToStringUsingSparkExecutorID(row, SparkEnv.executorId()), Encoders.STRING()
        );
stringDataSet.show();
```

And the question is regarding the **doSomeTransformationFromRowToStringUsingSparkExecutorID** method.

This method needs the spark executor ID the row is being processed, in order to do some transformation.

As I need the Spark executor ID, I went to use `SparkEnv.executorId()` found in the official documentation.

Unfortunately, above is not working, as `Non-static method 'executorId()' cannot be referenced from a static context`

Is `SparkEnv.executorId()` even the good way to get the executor ID in this scenario?

If yes, how to workaround this Non-static method 'executorId()' issue please?

If not, what is the best alternative to get the executor ID please?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkEnv.html) `SparkEnv` class has `static` method [`get`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkEnv.html#get--) for getting `SparkEnv` instance. And on this instance you can call [`executorId()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkEnv.html#executorId--) method (which is not static):

```java
import org.apache.spark.SparkEnv

SparkEnv sparkEnv = SparkEnv.get();
String executorId = sparkEnv.executorId();
```

```java
final Dataset<Row> rowDataSet = sparkSession.read()[...].load();
final Dataset<String> stringDataSet = rowDataSet
        .map(
                (MapFunction<Row, String>) row ->
                        doSomeTransformationFromRowToStringUsingSparkExecutorID(row, SparkEnv.get().executorId()), Encoders.STRING()
        );
stringDataSet.show();
```

Comment: Thank you @Boris! (hope you get this before it gets removed  )